# Does C# Dictionary<TKey, TValue> guarantee an iteration order?

Tags: c#, dictionary

There are several questions on this site stating that Dictionaries don't have a guaranteed iteration order (which is typical of hash tables). However, I'm having trouble proving this out for the Dictionary class:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var rand = new Random();
var randomList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
    .Select(i => new { x = rand.NextDouble().ToString(), i })
    .ToArray();
foreach (var t in randomList) { dict[t.x] = t.i; }
Console.WriteLine(dict.Values.SequenceEqual(randomList.Select(t => t.i))); // prints True
```

Is this some undocumented behavior of the Dictionary class? Or am I simply missing something with my example?

EDIT: weirdly, this behavior is maintained for awhile but eventually stops as the dictionary gets larger. The cutoff seems to be 33899 (still prints true, whereas with 33900 it prints false). I suppose this could be related to a hash collision in this particular example.

Comment: This is a documented behavior. The documentation says that it produces the pairs in an order of its choosing and it does so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure representing a value and its
>   key. **The order in which the items are returned is undefined**.

So while it may look like it's consistent, there's no guarantee that it'll remain that way in the future or across implementations.

Answer (score 4):

The iteration order of Dictionary is not guaranteed. In practice, that means at the moment in does iterate in a consistent fashion, but in the future that may change.

If you write code that relies on Dictionary iterating in a deterministic way, then it's your problem if that breaks with a future .NET release as MS have advised not to rely on it.